# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have googled and also gone through a list of similar questions available on Stack as well, but unfortunately none is helping me around in solving the issue.

Below is what im doing, Im calling a `PartialView` from my main view, but my PartialView is not getting called.

**Below is my code.**

```
     $("#Status").live("change", function () {
         $.getJSON("/../My_Controller/My_Partial_View", { Parameter1: $("#Parameter1").attr("value")}, function (data) {
           My logic         
         });
     });
```

But the following code is not working and im getting the following error.
Although this code works fine in my other solutions and my PartialViews does gets called.
[image]

This is the error i'm getting.

**Updates**

If i pass the parameters in this manner then my code is visiting the partial view.

```
 $.get("/../My_Controller/My_Partial_View?Param1=1", function (data) {
      $("#TableEmployee tbody").append(data);
 });
```

Comment: @Matheletics, then which alternative i should use? I want the get the partialView upon the leave of a certain textbox

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on/ -- The new `live`.

Comment: @elclanrs yes, this is what i tried, $("#My_Control").on("change", i have added an alert code to test, its giving me an alert, but again its showing the same error,Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation and not entering the PartialView in the controller

Comment: There are various way to use `on`, look for "event delegation".

Comment: The "on" event handler is working fine, as the alert is getting popped up on the change of the value or click and other events, but the partial view is not getting called.

Comment: what is the code My Logic?

Comment: @nathanhayfield "My Logic" is the code that will be executed once the partial view is visited.

Comment: i know that, what does it look like...

Comment: Then you didn't even need `.live()` since you're querying by id. You can simply use `.change()`. Also you want `.val()` instead of `.attr('value')`

Comment: But my issue is, y is it not visiting the PartialView, the "MyLogic" part will the issue of later, once the PartialView is visited. Right now its not even entering the PartialView.

Comment: @elclanrs that was just to explain my issue, in my actual code im passion 7 parameters to my PartialView

Comment: @elclanrs , i have tried using .change directly and again its giving me the same error.

Comment: I don't know what your particular issue is, and debugging minified code won't help much. I'm just going line by line, char by char, fixing what doesn't seem right. You might need to post more code, or try to reproduce the issue with some dummy data on jsFiddle or something. Open devtools, add a few breakpoints, and track the call stack trace, it's all I can tell you for now...

Comment: @elclanrs , please check the updates of my question, now if i pass the parameter to my controller as shown in the update, then my PartialView is getting called perfectly and it is also returning as per My coded logic. I dont understand what's the issue with parameter passing method.

Comment: are you sure it isn't a naming issue? in one sample you used `Parameter1` and the other you used `Param1`.

Comment: Go to your console (the console tab to the right of Audits) where you should see the same error. On the right hand side of the console on the same line as the error, there is a down arrow. Click the down arrow. A list of file locations will appear, find the first one that is in your code. This will confirm that executing $.getJSON is what is causing the error.

Comment: .on vs .live has nothing to do with this

Comment: @KevinB no the naming is not an issue, the posted question is a sample code. My real code has the parameter names and values.

Comment: Yes, sorry i can see that from the graphic above. Did you see my other comment?

Comment: .on vs .live has nothing to do with this??? yes, in my case both are working fine.

Comment: No, the one above asking you to go to the console tab to trace the code

Comment: Also, add this before the ajax request, what is the result? `console.log({ Parameter1: $("#Parameter1").attr("value")})`

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to specify request type and the return type

Here is sample:

```
 $.ajax({ 
            url: "yoururl", 
            data: "parameter1=1", 
            success: successevent, 
            type: 'GET', 
            dataType: 'json' 
        });
```

Hope this help!